# Distinct value in object of array and remaining values into another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

This is the array of javascript objects. I want these javascript objects will merge into a single javascript object according to their same property value and remaining values come into another array of named **info**.

This is the original array:

```
const array = [
    {
        price: 27,
        colors: "BLACK",
        size: "S"
    },
    {
        price: 23,
        colors: "GREEN",
        size: "S"
    },
    {
        price: 0,
        colors: "GREEN",
        size: "M"
    },
    {
        price: 0,
        colors: "OLIVE",
        size: "S"
    },
    {
        price: 65,
        colors: "RED",
        size: "S"
    },
    {
        price: 12,
        colors: "RED",
        size: "M"
    },
    {
        price: 12,
        colors: "BLACK",
        size: "L"
    },
    {
        price: 34,
        colors: "RED",
        size: "L"
    },
    {
        price: 43,
        colors: "OLIVE",
        size: "M"
    },
    {
        price: 23,
        colors: "OLIVE",
        size: "L"
    },
    {
        price: 34,
        colors: "GREEN",
        size: "L"
    },

]
```

This is the required array:

```
 [
    {
        colors: "BLACK",
        info: [{size: "S", price: 27}, {size: "L", price: 12}]
    },
    {
        colors: "GREEN",
        info: [{size: "S", price: 23}, {size: "M", price: 0}, {size: "L", price: 23}]
    },
    {
        colors: "RED",
        info: [{size: "S", price: 65}, {size: "M", price: 12}, {size: "L", price: 34}]
    },
    {
        colors: "OLIVE",
        info: [{size: "S", price: 0}, {size: "M", price: 43}, {size: "L", price: 23}]
    },
]
```

Kindly provide me with some solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `reduce` to group to an object by `colors` prop and then `Object.values` to get the array of values

```js
const array = [    {        price: 27,        colors: "BLACK",        size: "S"    },    {        price: 23,        colors: "GREEN",        size: "S"    },    {        price: 0,        colors: "GREEN",        size: "M"    },    {        price: 0,        colors: "OLIVE",        size: "S"    },    {        price: 65,        colors: "RED",        size: "S"    },    {        price: 12,        colors: "RED",        size: "M"    },    {        price: 12,        colors: "BLACK",        size: "L"    },    {        price: 34,        colors: "RED",        size: "L"    },    {        price: 43,        colors: "OLIVE",        size: "M"    },    {        price: 23,        colors: "OLIVE",        size: "L"    },    {        price: 34,        colors: "GREEN",        size: "L"    },]

const res = Object.values(array.reduce((acc,{colors,...rest}) => {
  (acc[colors]??={colors,info:[]}).info.push(rest)
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```